# WPF DataTrigger on ListViewItem.IsSelected

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview, triggers

I have a ListView, styled like this:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridViewColumn Header="Reset" Width="60">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ResetThisItem}" />
                </DataTemplate>
             </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>             
        </GridViewColumn>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

In the ViewModel-Class I have the property "ResetThisItem".

I want this Property get set to true when the user selects a complete row of the ListView. If the item gets deselected, nothing should happen.

I know I need DataTriggers here, but I don't know where, because I don't realize where I have access to the ListViewItem.IsSelected and my ViewModel.ResetThisItem and how to bind between those in xaml...

Any hints appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Not 100% sure, so a comment must be enough: Create a new ItemContainerStyle for your listview, but don't override the template, there you should have access to your ViewModel and your ListViewItem.

Comment: @dowhilefor: Thats what I tried, but I didn't figure out how to relate to the ViewModel from the Setter of the DataTrigger...

Comment: Remember that the Binding always relates to the DataContext, if you set the view model as the datacontext, there shouldn't be a problem. So your DataTrigger will automatically refere to the ViewModel. But if you overwrite that behavior, by assigning another object as the DataContext, you need another way. so <ItemContainerStyle><Style TargetType="ListViewItem"><Style.Triggers><DataTrigger Binding={ResetThisItem}><Setter Property="IsSelected" ... should work.

Comment: I don't touch the data context. But I want it the other way around <DataTrigger Binding="IsSelected" Value="True"><Setter Property="{Binding ResetThisItem}" Value="True"/>

Comment: Well you could use a very simple setter in your container style for that. But i would maybe completely change that approach and use commands for that. If your element is selected, a command will be fired which is handled in your view model. I would never use properties to trigger actions, like your ResetThisItem sounds. A property should be a state, not a temporary action just to trigger something.

Comment: No, the ResetThisItem is just a flag which resets this item, when the user clicks on "Reset selected Items".
I just want to make it easier for the user and check the "ResetThisItem"-Checkbox when he clicks (and selects) the full row of the listview.

Comment: Do you want your solution in C#, VB or XAML?

Comment: preferrably without code, only xaml

Answer (score 0):

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding ResetThisItem, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Reset" Width="60">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ResetThisItem}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

This is probably the simplest way to accomplish what you are after. Let me know if you prefer a code approach or a different angle. I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Almost. But I want the stillbox still be checked, when the user deselects an item.